# Random variables in Java

Tags: java, random

My professor asked us to generate random variables between 0 and 0.5. I wrote this code:

```
public class Random_Number_Generator {

  double randomGenerator()  {
    Random generator = new Random();
    double num = generator.nextDouble() * (0.5 - 0);   
    return num;
  }
}
```

But my professor is saying this code is generating random *numbers* not random *variables*. What could this mean?

Comment: Your prof needs to explain [him|her]self better. Maybe the intent is to store the numbers somewhere, like an array.

Comment: Can you please give me your homework details??? Like what your teacher exactly asked you to do???

Comment: Is there a question in this question? (And btw, why are you subtracting a constant zero? You can probably do `0.5 - 0` in your head.)

Comment: I understand all that....but according to my professor....this code is generating random numbers between 0 and 0.5 but he wants random variables between 0 and 0.5

Comment: do you want to create float variables whose values are 0 and 0.5 ?

Comment: Didn't your professor say any more than this? A [random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is a concept in probability which doesn't make sense in this context. You could implement a random variable (the mathematical concept) by generating random numbers (as you did). I'm afraid you'll have to ask your professor to clarify what he means.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I misread the post; the following should be read with that in mind.

---

In that code, `num` and `generators` are local *variables*. A random *number* (a *value*) is assigned to the *variable* called `num` using the Random *object* named by the `generator` *variable*. Finally,  the *value* stored in the *variable* `num` is returned from the method.

In any case, [`generator.nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) returns a value between `[0,1)` so to get a value between `[0,0.5)`, just scale it by half: divide it by two or, *as done*, multiply it by a half.

The `- 0` in the above code is silly, but "okay" because `(0.5 - 0) == 0.5`.

---

(Also, it is good to get into the practice of  to creating *one* Random instance and re-using it .. although this issue is more obvious in .NET.)

Comment: I understand all that....but according to my professor....this code is generating random numbers between 0 and 0.5 but he wants random variables between 0 and 0.5

Comment: @RahulBhatia Now I am confused. That makes no sense at all, and it looks like I misread the initial post! I would suggest asking the instructor for clarification including sample output :) Perhaps the instructor means "random variable *names*"?

Answer (score 1):

Now, actual *random variable* is, as far as I know, a *function* that maps *values* to their *probability*. I don't think you're supposed to return a function, so I've scratched this: the closest thing to what I guess you're supposed to do:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class RandomVar
{
    TreeMap<Double, Integer> variables;

    public RandomVar()
    {
        variables = new TreeMap<Double, Integer>();

        int count = Main.RandGen.nextInt(15);
        double probabilityLeft = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            int toPut = Main.RandGen.nextInt(100);
            while (variables.containsValue(toPut)) toPut = Main.RandGen.nextInt(100);
            double prob = probabilityLeft * Main.RandGen.nextDouble();
            variables.put(prob, toPut);
        }
        int toPut = Main.RandGen.nextInt(100);
        while (variables.containsValue(toPut)) toPut = Main.RandGen.nextInt(100);
        double prob = probabilityLeft;
        variables.put(prob, toPut);
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        double rand = Main.RandGen.nextDouble();
        double sum = 0;
        for (double prob : variables.keySet()) //keySet() is sorted ascending
        {
            if (prob >= rand)
                return variables.get(prob);
        }
        return variables.get(variables.lastKey());
    }

    //Shows probabilities of values
    public void test()
    {
        for (double key : variables.keySet())
            System.out.println(key + " :: " + variables.get(key));
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static Random RandGen = new Random();    

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        RandomVar rv = new RandomVar();
        rv.test();
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i++)
            System.out.print(rv.getValue() + ", ");
    }
}
```

This is very lousy solution, basically a class which allows you to return values with a set (random) probability. I still don't know if this is what you professor wants though...

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    System.out.print(Random());
}

public static double Random() {
    double START = 0;
    double END = 0.5;
    Random random = new Random();
    double token = RandomNumber(START, END, random);
    return token;
}

public static double RandomNumber(double aStart, double aEnd, Random aRandom) {
    if (aStart > aEnd) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
    }
    // get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
    double range = aEnd - aStart;
    // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
    double fraction =  (range * aRandom.nextDouble());
    double randomNumber =  (fraction + aStart);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a very obscure way of doing the exact thing the asker is already proposing. Nothing here is significantly different from random.nextDouble() * 0.5d
Also, you did not explain your intention in this code.